# what is the diffrence between TCP/IP model and TCP/IP Stack and between libpcap and divert socket?

Tags: sockets, stack, ip

I found this image from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9UWZ.png):

[image: Taken from this site]

### Questions:

1. Does the TCP/IP stack means the 4 layers (excluding the HW layer) on right?
2. As I understand the diffrence between libpcap and divert socket- they are both raw sockets, but with libpcap you can just sniffing while with divert Sockets you can detour and dump them, am I right?

Comment: No attribution for that copyrighted image - I'm not sure you're allowed to do what you just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The TCP stack is more or less equivalent to the parts in cyan
2. Yes, you can also change the (inject data)